# Can't get g:item_group_id to work

Tags: google

We have all similar products share the same [`g:item_group_id`](https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/6324507?hl=en) attribute. The goal is to [have them grouped together on the search results page](https://www.doofinder.com/support/the-data-feed/grouping-product-variants).

Even though the feed XML source looks correct, Google doesn't seem to be honouring our preferred grouping. On the Merchant Center product overview pages, the *Final attributes* area shows `g:item_group_id` with our  values set, but other than that they look as if nothing happened, and no grouping was requested. No errors are shown in there either though.

The only relevant resource I found is https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Shopping-and-Merchant-Center/Should-item-group-id-values-show-in-my-Raw-Feed-Attributes-in/td-p/1752985 but it doesn't open anymore.

Is there something obvious that I'm missing?